# Fancybox - cannot open a facebook like box within an iframe

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, fancybox

am new to js and have tried to open a fancybox iframe containing my facebook fan page like box upon the first load of my website with no success.
I have made all the calls to the js files in fancybox and the apropriate css in the header section
I am trying to include code in the index page in order to display the iframe on page load with no success, the iframe just doesn't show. here's the code that i use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".iframe" ).fancybox({
        'width'             : '75%',
        'height'            : 440,
        'autoScale'         : false,
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
        'type'              : 'iframe',
        'href'              : "www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FPalindrom%2F104421159704142&amp;width=600&amp;height=258&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color=%2399c844&amp;stream=false&amp;header=false&amp;appId=391204344279942"
    });
$(".iframe").eq(0).trigger('click');​        
});
</script>

<a id="iframe"></a>
```

Solved! thanks guys! managed to get it to open using the $.fancybox with no need for an anchor. Here's the code i used maybe it will help someone else that is also a novice when it comes to jquery and fancybox (i also added a delay timer):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function() {
  // Do something after 5 seconds

$.fancybox({
    'width'             : 620,
    'height'            : 260,
    'autoScale'         : true,
    'transitionIn'      : 'fade',
    'transitionOut'     : 'elastic',
    'openEffect'        : 'fade',
    'closeEffect'       : 'elastic',
    'type'              : 'iframe',
    'href'              : "http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FPalindrom%2F104421159704142&width=600&height=258&colorscheme=light&show_faces=true&border_color=%2399c844&stream=false&header=false&appId=391204344279942"
});
}, 5000);
```

Comment: What does `.iframe` match? Is this a link (as it should be), or the iframe itself? By the way, I think one can trigger fancybox without any link element, using the `$.fancybox` method. This looks more appropriate for your situation.

Comment: i would like to see the code for that. I am only interrested in using fancybox v 2.0 so as when my page loads an iframe pops up with the facebook like box for my fan page.

Answer (score 1):

What about adding `http://` before `www`?

so this option

```
'href'  : "www.facebook.com/....
```

should look like

```
'href'  : "http://www.facebook.com/...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".iframe" ).fancybox({ // .iframe - defined class here
        'width'             : '75%',
        'height'            : 440,
        'autoScale'         : false,
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
        'type'              : 'iframe',
        'href'              : "www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FPalindrom%2F104421159704142&amp;width=600&amp;height=258&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color=%2399c844&amp;stream=false&amp;header=false&amp;appId=391204344279942"
    });
$(".iframe").eq(0).trigger('click');​        
});
</script>

<a id="iframe"></a> <!-- #iframe - defined an ID here -->
```

Maybe you can try to change id `<a id="iframe"></a>` to class of `<a class="iframe"></a>`

JsFiddle Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/agriboz/sZzyn/2102/)

Comment: You can also do `$(".iframe").fancybox({//options}).eq(0).trigger("click");`